# Change tag synonym display handling in /tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, information-display

While browsing the unpopular end of https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular to see if there were any tags that probably shouldn't be, I was *shocked* that [zombie](/questions/tagged/zombie) was empty.  Surely there are lots of questions on there about zombie processes, right?

And of course there are, but they're tagged as [zombie-process](/questions/tagged/zombie-process) which [zombie](/questions/tagged/zombie) is a synonym of.

**Could the display in `/tags` be changed to better handle synonyms?**

Some alternatives:

- Suppress display of synonyms altogether; searching displays the master tag as when tagging questions.  (Problem because it's useful to also have a straight textual search for tags instead of being second-guessed.)
- Display synonyms on equal footing as the master tag; [zombie](/questions/tagged/zombie) and [zombie-process](/questions/tagged/zombie-process) both have **× 49** displayed next to them.  (Probably too confusing if both are visible.)
- Add some other indicator that slave tags are synonyms, e.g., **(s)**.
- Sort by popularity then synonymy; this would be less of a problem in `/tags` if all the synonyms were clumped together, though without an indicator it might be confusing at the intersection point.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A good solution could be an option to filter tag-synonyms on the tag page. I think a simple hide/show checkbox would work fairly well.

[image: Mockup for "Hide tag synonyms" checkbox]